# how can I import components in next within a route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I import the navbar in the pages/index folder as below, it works fine

```html
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Navbar from '../components/navbar'
import Footer from '../components/footer'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      
      
      <Navbar />
      Home
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

but when I import from a route e.g `pages/admin/index.js` as below I can't seem to be able to access the components. I have tried changing the import from `"../components/admin_navbar"` adding dots to the path upto `"....../components/admin_navbar"` but cant seem to resolve the issue.

```html
import Navbar from '../components/admin_navbar'
const Admin = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            Admin
        </div>
         );
}
 
export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `admin` component in one level deep folder so you need to go into the parent of parent and that is `../../`. It goes like this only. `...` doesn't work.

```
import Navbar from '../../components/admin'
const Admin = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            Admin
        </div>
         );
}
 
export default Admin;
```